# Cannot get full references list with bibtex

Tags: bibliographies

I just installed TeXmaker on my Windows machine. I downloaded TeX template and then put some references in the references.bib file.

However it only displays the first reference. No matter what I add it doesn't show the others. I also tried to run the commands many times.

First run pdflatex, biblatex, pdflatex 2x, view pdf and it is not updating. My template and references list can be found here: https://github.com/shnigi/scientificwriting what in earth I am doing wrong here?

Comment: `\documentclass[english]`  You trouble starts at the very very first line.

Comment: Fixing that obvious error, bibtex  complains about a missing bibliographystyle. If i add `\bibliographystyle{plain}`, i get a bibliograhy.

Comment: I added the \bibliographystyle{plain} but it still gives me only the first reference. This is the original template I am trying to use. https://github.com/UniversityHelsinkiTKTL/tktltiki2 Still don't get it. I reverted back to the original template, but still it doesn't work.

Comment: With your example, i get only one item in the bibliography. Just one item was cited. Use `Sample text and a reference~\cite{neurognosis,transportpolicy}`.

Comment: Shouldn't it list all the references in this line? \bibliography{references}
I have two references in the bib file, I thought this line should list everything in it?

Comment: No, if you want also all uncited references use `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: No. This is by design. The tool extracts only the entries that have been cited. If you need all, without citing them, use  `\nocite{*}`.

Comment: Ah ok, now its clear! Thanks a lot. @TeXnician if you could add your comment as answer I check it as correct.

Comment: Also @Johannes_B thanks for clearing things out =)

Comment: potential duplicate: [Latex Why are my references empty](http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350785/579)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem with the bibliography is that by default only those entries you explicitly cite are printed. To have all items of your bibliography in the list you can use `\nocite{*}`.