# Why aren't my newest Mendeley references not recognised in LaTeX?

Tags: bibliographies, bibtex, mendeley

I am using MacTeX, I have updated and synced the folder in Mendeley that I have connected to BibTeX. The reference is appearing in my reference.bib folder but when I try to use it in my project, it is not finding a database entry.

Can someone please help with this? It would be much appreciated as I am a new user and still trying to figure it out!

Comment: if you rerun bibtex the references should appear or you should get a message in the bibtex log (blg) saying why not, But as you have not shown the input nor the output nor the error log. Hard to guess anything.

Comment: You need to show us some code of what exactly it is you are doing. As far as I remember Mendeley is just a data management software so not related to LaTeX other than it can produce a `.bib` file. It is not related in the rest of the processing.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. Based on the limited information you've provided so far, it sounds like all you've done is to (re)run Mendeley to insert a few more entries in the bib file called `references.bib`. To *use* these entries in the document, you must (a) `\cite` them and `(b)` re-run BibTeX, followed by two more LaTeX runs. The two LaTeX runs are needed to (i) insert the formatted entries into the bibliography and (ii) provide all needed information to the citation call-outs.

Comment: To follow up on @Mico's comment, this answer might be helpful: [Latex Why are my references empty](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/350785)